# R studio initialization stuck in an old version

Tags: r, installation, version

I have installed the most recent version of R just some minutes ago (version 4.04).

But when I open R studio and run `version` in my console, it appears to be opened still using the 3.6.1 version:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

How can I open R studio trough the new version of R I just installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to uninstall the old versions of R gathered in your computer from the Panel Control and RStudio will initiate with the oldest version of R.